# JPA @OrderColumn not ordering the list

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, in-memory-database

I've defined an "Ordinal" INT column in the Child table. For some reason, the automatic ordering is not taking affect. I'm testing this with integration tests that use an in-memory db. Maybe that matters?

```
public class ParentEntity
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @OrderColumn(name = "Ordinal")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentId", nullable = false)
    private List<ChildEntity> childEntities = new ArrayList<>();

public class ChildEntity
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentId", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private ParentEntity parent;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you understand thinking of `automatic ordering`? I have ran the code and it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks. This was working after all. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that one of your Entity should be the [owner of the bidirectional (ManyToOne) relationship:](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Inverse_Relationships.2C_Target_Foreign_Keys_and_Mapped_By)

```
public class ParentEntity
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")//this mappedBy tells that ChildEntity is the owner of the entity
    @OrderColumn(name = "Ordinal")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentId", nullable = false)
    private List<ChildEntity> childEntities = new ArrayList<>();

public class ChildEntity
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentId", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private ParentEntity parent;
```

Excerpt from [this page:](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Inverse_Relationships.2C_Target_Foreign_Keys_and_Mapped_By)

> In JPA a ManyToOne relationship is always (well almost always)
>   required to define a OneToMany relationship, the ManyToOne always
>   defines the foreign key (JoinColumn) and the OneToMany must use a
>   mappedBy to define its inverse ManyToOne.

Check this page

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but according to [this page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype-indexbidir):   "if there is no such property on the child class, we can't think of the association as truly bidirectional (there is information available at one end of the association that is not available at the other end: the index). In this case, we can't map the collection as mappedBy"

Comment: I think you did not see that you have from Parent to Child a property and from Child to Parent another one. So, THERE IS such a property in the child class... meaning that quote from jboss is not valid in your case (that's why in my quote is written "well almost always"). Or do I get something wrong?